# refreshing multiple routes in simultaneously in express nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, http, express

**In my messaging app ,i wanna reload the page of other user so message can be added in realtime**

**Is there any way so I can reload '/profile/chat/:username/:id/' route of other user,since messages are adding correctly but newly recieved messages from mongodb other user page can be only seen after refreshing the page  **
***This is my route ***

```
router.post('/profile/chat/:username/:id/send',isLoggedIn,
      function(req,res){

  User.findById(req.user._id,function(err,primaryUser){
      if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      } else {







  if (primaryUser.messages.some((message) => message.id.toString() === 
   req.params.id.toString())) {




  User.findOneAndUpdate({username:req.user.username,
   "messages.id":req.params.id},
    {$push:
     {"messages.$.texts":

     {
      message:req.body.message,
      username:req.user.username
     }

     }
       },function(err,user){
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
     } else {

     User.findOneAndUpdate({username:req.params.username,
      "messages.id":req.user.id},
     {$push:
     {"messages.$.texts":

   {
      message:req.body.message,
      username:req.user.username
   }

    }
    },function(err,user){
    if (err) {
     throw err;
  } else {



  //What should  do here?
   //so i can reload '/profile/chat/:username/:id/' route of other 
   //user















 console.log("Debugg Point 3"); 

}
})   
console.log("Debugg Point 4");
res.redirect("back");
}
})





 }
   else {

   var primarySpace = {
     id:req.params.id,
     User:req.params.username
   }

   primaryUser.messages.push(primarySpace);
   primaryUser.save();


   User.findById(req.params.id,function(err,secondaryUser){
     if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {



   var secondarySpace = {
     id:req.user._id,
     User:req.user.username
   }

  secondaryUser.messages.push(secondarySpace);
  secondaryUser.save();


User.findOneAndUpdate({username:req.user.username,
 "messages.id":req.params.id},
{$push:
{"messages.$.texts":

{
message:req.body.message,
username:req.user.username
}

}
},function(err,user){
if (err) {
throw err;
} else {

  User.findOneAndUpdate({username:req.params.username,
 "messages.id":req.user.id},
{$push:
{"messages.$.texts":

{
message:req.body.message,
username:req.user.username
}

}
},function(err,user){
if (err) {
throw err;
} else {

 console.log("Debugg Point 1"); 

}
})   
console.log("Debugg Point 2");
res.redirect("back");
}
})  
    }
   })    
  }    
    }
  })

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a continuous webSocket connection between the other user's page and your server, your server cannot tell that other webpage that is not currently in the middle of a request to your server to refresh itself.  That's not how things are done with web pages.  At that point in time, your server has no connection at all to that other user's browser so it can't make that browser do anything.

The usual architecture for messaging apps would be for the other user's web page to have a continuous webSocket connection to the server.  Then, when new events happen on the server and the server wants to update that other webpage, it can just send that webpage events over the webSocket connection.  Code within the other user's webpage will then receive those events and can do whatever it wants with that info.  Ideally, it would just update the current web page dynamically with the new info.  But, it could also instruct the web page to do a refresh to load the whole page from scratch (though that is a lot less efficient for both client and server than just adding new content to the existing page).

A much less efficient architecture is for every message page in your app to just auto-refresh itself every once in a while to pick up new content.  That's a fairly inefficient architecture because it will likely be refreshing itself lots of times when there is nothing new (adding lots of extra load to the server) and because there will likely be a delay between when new data is available and when the web page refreshes itself.  A webSocket connection as described above it both more efficient and more responsive.

Comment: So should I use npm nodemon or npm reload ,which is better for this types of instances?

Comment: @saurabhpandey - I don't know what either of those has to do with the question.  Don't understand the context.